# Chrome extensions w/ Jquery. Wait for element/entire dom load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension basically select some buttons (size of clothes) and then press the checkout button of a shopping website. It's all fine until the checkout page.

This page is slow to load so i need to wait it to be loaded before executing the rest of the script. Any way to do it?

```
I tried $(document).on("load", function(){
//...
})
```

and other stuffs like this but doesnt work. Thanks you all!

Comment: I have one question about this. what does document refers to??
The current page ?

Comment: Because i navigate from an URL to another (the one for the checkout) so i dont know if using $(document).ready() in the middle of the script is fine

Comment: Anyway this doesnt work

Comment: Use MutationObserver or setInterval + clearInterval.